# filter DateTime field with now as reference in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetime, where-clause

I am trying to build a vb.net application with a where clause to filter data using a DateTime field.

My table contains 5 fields and more than 10000 rows. I wanna use a DateTime field to find all the rows older than 7 years from now. 
But this script will be re-used many times. So I don't wanna use this kind of where clause cause I don't wanna need to modify the where clause every time I wanna run the application :

```
select * from myTable WHERE myDateTimeField < '2006-09-07 00:00:00.000'
```

I'd like to find a way to write a where clause like this :

`select * from myTable WHERE myDateTimeField "is older than 7 years from NOW`"

I don't use VB.net very often (as you can see), so this thing is really bugging me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make use of `DateTime`:

```
Dim dateTime As DateTime
dateTime = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-7);
```

When you're building your SQL string just call `ToString` on your date (you can obviously format it however you need):

```
dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: Are you *recommending* passing a `DateTime` as a `string`?  That's never a good idea.

Comment: @MattJohnson - I agree, I always push dates onto the SQL Server side of the fence.  Since his original question was showing an attempt for a string date, that's what I assumed he wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

i think better would be provided you have SQL Server

```
strQuery = "select * from myTable WHERE myDateTimeField 
            <= DATEADD(YEAR, -7, GETDATE())"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDateTimeField < DATEADD(YEAR, -7, GETDATE())
```

That is if the data in the `myDateTimeField` is in the same *local* time zone of the sql server.

If your data is in UTC (which it often should be), then use:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDateTimeField < DATEADD(YEAR, -7, GETUTCDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a DSL for datetime.  Check out this blog post to get some ideas.

http://leecampbell.blogspot.com/2008/11/how-c-30-helps-you-with-creating-dsl.html

Good Luck

P.S.

If you need help translating it into vb.net just submit a comment.